# How to return a relational data from DB in ASP.Net Core Web API Controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have 3 relational table

1-Posts , 
2-Comments , 
3-Images

"Comments" and "Images" tables have "posts" Foreign Key . I want to return complete information about a post from all tables together in an ASP.Net Core Web API with GET Method . I know how to create controller and such things . My problem is about retrieving and returning data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `EFCore`, you can do this.

- Create an ApiController
- Inject your `DbContext` from `Constructor`
- Read data from `DB`
- Return data

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PostController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;//Your DbContext
    public PostController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var data = _dbContext.Post.Include(a=> a.Comments).Include(a=> a.Images).ToList();
        return Ok(data);
    }

}
```

In **.Net Core** `Lazy loading` is disable and when you select a table from database none relation loaded by default.

If you want get all data with relations you must use `Include` to load relations like this

```cs
dbContext.Post.Include(a=> a.Comments).Include(a=> a.Images).ToList();
```

your database tables should be like this

```cs
public class Post
{
    public ICollection<Images> Images { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
}
public class Comments
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
public class Images
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```